# What is the term for how a colon is used as a key value separator in English, and are there other similar characters in other languages?

Tags: terminology, punctuation

In English we often use colons as an informal `term: definition` separator or a `key: value` separator - like

> Birthdate: some date

Is there a term for this form of usage, and are there other characters used in other languages for this? In other words, can you point out other characters commonly used for this in various languages?

Comment: You said it yourself: "separator". Maybe you should ask on one of the programming SEs about other specialized terms. Also incidentally it's not about the metalanguage, it's about the programming language, most notoriously "\" vs. "/" across platforms.

Comment: yeah I'm not asking a programming language related question. I'm asking if I have the text in a document Birthday: 02/11/1990 what is the term for how the colon is used in this way - perhaps this is not linguistic but rather an orthographical question - although I figured orthography questions were allowed here.  As far as other languages part of question - For other languages maybe it would be more likely word for birthday > actual date?